# What is the best way to extend the functionality of an existing class of an existing 3rd party library?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Lets say for example that I am using lots of `pandas.DataFrames` in my code.  This is a really big class with lots of pieces, and it has a very functional-like API to it, where you tend to chain its method calls together.

It feels like it would be nice to easilly be able to add functionality to this existing class while still keeping the functional, flowing API in tact.

I wanted to turn this class into something a bit domain-specific in the interests of removing a lot of domain-specific boilerplate code that is often used when using this class.

Let's say in my dreams I'm to be able to do something like this:

```
pandas.read_csv('sales.csv') \
    .filter(items=['one', 'three']) \
    .apply(myTransformationFunction) \
    .saveToHivePartition(tablename = 'sales', partitionColumn = 'four') \
    .join(pandas.read_csv('employees.csv')) \
    .filter(items=['one','three','five']) \
    .saveToHivePartition(tablename = 'EmployeeMetrics', partitionColumn = 'ten')
```

In this example, `saveToHivePartition` is a custom method that does a lot of stuff to atomically save something to HDFS at the correct location and then adds that information tot he hive metadatastore.  Super useful!

Obviously the "easy" answer is to simply create a standalone function that I can pass a `DataFrame` object into along with the other paramaters that I need.  Every time I want to perform the save, I need to encapsulate the dataframe into a variable and then pass that variable into a separate function.  Nowhere near as clean as the above example!

So then the next thing that comes to mind is to create some cool new `SuperDataFrame` class that is a superset of `DataFrame`.  The only issue with that approach is: How do you even construct it?  i can't change `pandas.read_csv()` to start returning my new class.  I can't cast a base class into a subclass.  I could have `SuperDataFrame` be... a wrapper for the dataframe class?  But then I think that any time I want to call a base `DataFrame` function, It would have to be like this:

```
SuperDataFrame(pandas.read_csv('sales.csv')) \
    .df.filter .... \
    .df.apply .... \
    .saveToHivePartition .... \
    .df.join .... \
    .df.filter .... \
    .saveToHivepartition ....
```

I don't even think this works, because this assumes that whenever pandas performs a function, it mutates the `DataFrame` in-place, which I'm pretty sure it doesn't even do.

Any ideas? Or is this just a bad thing?

Comment: Yeah, this question is bordering on being off-topic, but I'd still like to see the answers it would produce. I think, unfortunately, `pandas` is just an example of a library that is designed in a way that is difficult to extend using inheritance. Anyway, I rarely see this sort of chained -method calls in Python. And you are right - most of the time the `DataFrame` is not modified in-place unless you explicitely pass that as an argument, and not all methods have that option anyway - e.g. `apply`.

Comment: I think your example as written doesn't make sense, because you first filter to "one" and "three", then later filter to "one", "three", and "five", but "five" won't be there if you already filtered down to just "one" and "three".

Comment: @BernBarn it is presumed that "five" was introduced by the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [constructor-override properties](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#override-constructor-properties) to ensure that pandas operations return an instance of your new class.  A simple example:

```
class MyDF(pandas.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDF

    def myMethod(self):
        return "I am cool"

>>> d = MyDF([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
>>> d.filter(["A", "B"]).apply(lambda c: c**2).myMethod()
'I am cool'
```

Of course, you'll also have to make your own Series subclass and potentially define [custom data slots](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#define-original-properties) if you also want to be able to handle Series.

That said, it's not clear to me that your example really warrants this.  You can already chain method calls on ordinary DataFrames, so if all you want to do is save some intermediate stages, it's not that onerous to do:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('sales.csv') \
    .filter(items=['one', 'three', 'five']) \
    .apply(myTransformationFunction)

data2 = data.join(pandas.read_csv('employees.csv')) \
    .filter(items=['one', 'three'])

saveToHivePartition(data, tablename='sales', partitionColumn='four')
saveToHivePartition(data2, tablename='EmployeeMetrics', partitionColumn='ten')
```

(I changed the order of the filters due to the issue I mentioned in my comment on the question.  It doesn't make sense to filter to a smaller subset first and a larger subset later; the larger subset won't be there later because some of it will already have been filtered out.)

The mere ability to write things as method chains isn't inherently an advantage.  I would be especially dubious of chaining methods like your `.saveToHivePartition`, which presumably are called only for their side effects.  It makes sense to chain methods when they're acting in assembly-line fashion, each taking the input of the previous one and modifying it to pass to the next.  But having methods that just do a side effect and return the unchanged object doesn't do much to make the code more readable.

Also, note that this solution is specific to pandas.  In general, if classes in some library create instances of one another, the library must be carefully designed to allow subclassing in a way that preserves the relationships among the classes.  Pandas has done this with the constructor-override mechanism I described, but it wasn't always like that, and before that, it was difficult to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to extend the `DataFrame` class. To keep the fluent interface, you could just create your own `custom.read_csv`

```
def read_csv(file):
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv(file)
    return SuperDataFrame(dataframe)
```

You start by calling that function, and the rest of the function calls remain as they are. You just add to your new dataframe the functions you want.

Alternatively (python-specific hack), you can  probably *monkey-patch* your own function directly into the original dataframe class in the module where you import it, but don't...

Comment: Ah, i thought about this answer as well, but what would the `SuperDataFrame.__init__` function look like, such that the `SuperDataFrame` inherited every attribute of the `DataFrame`? I don't think you can do something as easy/silly as calling `self = DataFrame` within the `__init__` call.  If it were as easy as calling SuperDataFrame(dateframe), i wouldn't even need to custom function, i would just call `SuperDataFrame(pandas.read_csv())`

Comment: @JHixson In this case, you would just *inherit* the `__init__`  - I would definitely not mess around with the `__init__`, but you could add methods like `save_to_hive_partition`

Comment: I agree, just leave it to the superclass init, and add the methods you want

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga does that mean that the answer the original question of "How do you even construct it?" would be as simple as calling `SuperDataFrame(pandas.read_csv())` given the inherited `__init__` ?

Comment: @JHixson The real problem is, as you intuited, that methods that return a *new* data frame directly call `panda.core.frame.DataFrame(...)` instead of `type(self)(...)` in the source code, so every method that returns a *new* data frame returns the super-class, in this case, instead of your derived class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga daaaaw, really?  I should have looked at that before starting down this path, haha

Comment: @JHixson Yeah, try something simple like `class SuperDataFrame(panda.DataFrame): pass`. You'll see that you can use SuperDataFrame to construct a DataFrame just as you'd hope. You can even wrap a call to `SuperDataFrame(pd.read_csv(...))`. However, if you use something like `.apply` or `.copy` you will get a plain `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame` back. Like I said, the library is not designed to be easily extensible. Well, maybe they do provide some sort of abstract wrapper. I don't know. But definitely not if you subclass directly from `pd.DataFrame`.